# Disable Ability to Take or Upload Photo on HTML File Input with Limited File Types

Tags: android, html, ios, user-interface, mobile

Wondering if anyone can help me out here. I have an input on a webpage that should only allow document files (not images). I have the "accept" parameter like so:

```
accept=".txt,.rtf,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.zip"
```

However it seems that on mobile phones (have tested multiple iOS devices and Android) it gives the user the ability to take a photo or upload.

Does anyone know a surefire way to prevent these options from showing? Typically iOS/Android have mechanisms that will respect the functionality of the HTML (like changing the keyboard for an input type number vs text), but here it seems like it doesn't care that I am trying to limit the file type.

In my case, the server will catch it and reject the image if they do upload it, but I'd really like them not to even get to that step by hiding that option.

On iOS, I'd like it to just say "browse", and on Android I'd like it to just say "Documents".

I realize my options are probably incredibly limited here, but I just wanted to know if I'm being stupid and if anyone had run into this issue with uploading files on mobile devices.

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Comment: I did it by changing the field from input file to a button in the html and then I call a view controller listing the files that I allow them to upload, once choose, I call another JS function in the page to inject the file in base64 format

Comment: Did you find a solution?